# Z5 NON Cpu lens atttached

Tags: nikon

I got this error message on my nikon Z5 Ether no lens is attached or the attached lens is non-CPU lens. to shoot with a non -CPU lens, change the shooting mode to P, S, A, or M

I did all cleaning trouble shooting and same issue
Changed the lens same issue
and autofocus  not working at all with any mode

Comment: What lens is attached? It it a Nikon CPU lens?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a non-CPU lens, that's to be expected. You must shoot in P, S, A, or M mode to use such a lens.